# apt-get upgrade got aborted how to recover?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm afraid I made a kind of a booboo.

While performing an `apt-get upgrade` I accidentally logged out, thus aborting the upgrade midway. Now I can't restart the upgrade.

`apt-get upgrade` says there are no packages to upgrade...

`apt-get update` gives errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/main/binary-armel/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/contrib/binary-armel/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/non-free/binary-armel/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

[several more of these]
```

I tried these without results:

- `apt-get install -f`
- `dpkg --configure -a`
- `rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*; apt-get update`

Comment: Maybe you should ask on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Kevinrob : Will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use purge and autoremove to fully remove the installed packages, and try update/upgrade again.

Comment: There may be some files installed still lying around somewhere